# Faster way to unlist a list of large matrices?

Tags: r

I have a list of large matrices. All these matrices have the same number of rows and I want to "unlist" them and bind all their columns together. Below is a piece of code that I wrote, but I am not sure if this is the best I can achieve in terms of computational efficiency.

```
# simulate
n <- 10
nr <- 24
nc <- 8000
test <- list()
set.seed(1234)
for (i in 1:n){
  test[[i]] <- matrix(rnorm(nr*nc),nr,nc)
}

> system.time( res <- matrix( as.numeric( unlist(test) ) ,nr,nc*n) )
 user  system elapsed 
0.114   0.006   0.120
```

Comment: Maybe try `do.call(cbind,test)`

Comment: @Tensibai Thanks, I tried it and it is indeed much faster. Will update my post accordingly. Any intuition why it is much faster?

Comment: There's fewest copy and casting I think

Comment: Use the `microbenchmark` package for benchmarking. `system.time` is not suitable if timings are that short.

Comment: @Tensibai Okay will do, thanks again!

Comment: @Roland Thanks Roand, I didn't know that, will edit my question accordingly using `microbenchmark`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To work on a list and call a function on all objects, `do.call` is my usual first idea, along with `cbind` here to bind by column all objects.

For `n=100` (with others answers for sake of completeness):

```
n <- 10
nr <- 24
nc <- 8000
test <- list()
set.seed(1234)
for (i in 1:n){
  test[[i]] <- matrix(rnorm(nr*nc),nr,nc)
}

require(data.table)
ori <- function() { matrix( as.numeric( unlist(test) ) ,nr,nc*n) }
Tensibai <- function() { do.call(cbind,test) }
BrodieG <- function() { `attr<-`(do.call(c, test), "dim", c(nr, nc * n)) }
nicola <- function() { setattr(unlist(test),"dim",c(nr,nc*n)) }

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(r1 <- ori(),
               r2 <- Tensibai(),
               r3 <- BrodieG(),
               r4 <- nicola(), times=10)
```

Results:

```
Unit: milliseconds
             expr       min        lq     mean    median        uq      max neval cld
      r1 <- ori() 23.834673 24.287391 39.49451 27.066844 29.737964 93.74249    10   a
 r2 <- Tensibai() 17.416232 17.706165 18.18665 17.873083 18.192238 21.29512    10   a
  r3 <- BrodieG()  6.009344  6.145045 21.63073  8.690869 10.323845 77.95325    10   a
   r4 <- nicola()  5.912984  6.106273 13.52697  6.273904  6.678156 75.40914    10   a
```

As for the why (in comments), @nicola did give the answer about it, there's less copy than original method.

All methods gives the same result:

```
> identical(r1,r2,r3,r4)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems that `do.call` beats the other method due to a copy made during the `matrix` call. What is interesting is that you can avoid that copy using the `data.table::setattr` function which allows to set attributes *by reference*, avoiding any copy. I omitted also the `as.numeric` part, since it is not necessary (`unlist(test)` is already `numeric`). So:

```
require(microbenchmark)
require(data.table)
f1<-function() setattr(unlist(test),"dim",c(nr,nc*n))
f2<-function() do.call(cbind,test)
microbenchmark(res <-f1(),res2 <- f2(),times=10)
#Unit: milliseconds
#        expr       min        lq      mean   median        uq      max neval
# res <- f1()  4.088455  4.183504  7.540913  4.44109  4.988605 35.05378    10
#res2 <- f2() 18.325302 18.379328 18.776834 18.66857 19.100681 19.47415    10
identical(res,res2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 4):

I think I have a better one.  We can avoid some of the overhead from `cbind` since we *know* these all have the same number of rows and columns.  Instead, we use `c` knowing that the underlying vector nature of the matrices will allow us to re-wrap them into the correct dimensions:

```
microbenchmark(
  x <- `attr<-`(do.call(c, test), "dim", c(nr, nc * n)), 
  y <- do.call(cbind, test)
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#                                                   expr       min        lq
#  x <- `attr<-`(do.call(c, test), "dim", c(nr, nc * n))  4.435943  4.699006
#                              y <- do.call(cbind, test) 19.339477 19.567063
#      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#  12.76214  5.209938  9.095001 379.77856   100  a
#  21.64878 20.000279 24.210848  26.02499   100   b

identical(x, y)
# [1] TRUE
```

If you have varying number of columns you can probably still do this with some care in computing the total number of columns.

Comment: This is really surprisingly fast! Thanks for the answer. Two questions: 1. These matrices in my real application have different number of columns, is this method still feasible? 2. I noticed that your method beats the `do.call(cbind, test)` in all aspects except the `max` amount of time (the `max` is 379.77856), why is that?

Comment: @EricWang, you should check, but so long as they are the same number of rows, and you specify the correct number of columns (i.e. sub-in number of columns for `nc * n`), you should be fine.  Re time spike, I wouldn't read much into the max, likely ran into a system cleanup process.  I ran it again and got consistent performance across the board.